# Change flow of transaction on opensea

Tags: solidity, opensea

I have created an asset that is linked to a physical asset.

My transaction flow should be as the following:

1. Customer buys NFT via opensea
2. Customer's ETH and NFT is transferred to an escrow contract
3. Customer visits other website and wants to retrieve his physical asset (basically clicks a button and fills out his return address)
4. When the customer receives the physical asset he confirms that he has received the asset
5. The customer gets the NFT and the seller gets the ETH

I am struggling to implement the escrow contract in my token. It seems to me that opensea does not allow to change the transaction flow.

Any help is highly appreciated!

Kr

Answer (score 0):

The way you described it won't work because your flow has the customer interacting with the OpenSea contract but asking for NFT to be transferred to your escrow contract.

Have a think about your design - if you really want to offer escrow on NFTs you'll have to buy the NFT yourself and then set up an escrow contract.